# Error: "'FileName.docx" has been damaged and can't be opened'" in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, document

I am trying to open documents but getting error. How do I resolve it?
This is headache for me, Any kind of document is not opening in my application.
I am trying to open PDF file using "PDF Reader" but getting error like this:

```
"Unable to Open"
```

Please suggest me.
See my code below.

```
string file = "test.docx";
IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

if (isf.FileExists(file))
{
     isf.DeleteFile(file);
}

var filerun = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(file);
StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile fileopen = await folder.GetFileAsync(file);
await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(fileopen);
```

Comment: You're saying you're trying to open a PDF file, but the file you're actually trying to open is a Word document. whhich one of the 2 is it?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are creating a totaly empty file and then try to open it with *Word* or *PDFReader*.

On Windows Phone you cannot open with *Word* an emty file just named *filename.docx* - try to create on computer a textfile *file.txt*, rename it to *file.docx*, copy to your phone, and then open via *Files App* - it won't work.

File extension only helps to determine the file type, but the most important is what is inside the file.

You should be able to open for example a file created with *Word*. Here is a sample example how I've done it - add a *docx* file (created for example on computer with *Word*) to your solution and change its *Build Action* to *Content*. Then try to open it like this:

```
private async void firstBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StorageFolder folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
    StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("sample.docx");
    await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
}
```

As I've tried - should work without problems. If you encounter some, [here is a working sample](http://1drv.ms/11rsIPp).

Nothing also stands on your way to prepare some empty *docx* templates and then inside the app just copy as new files and open them. You may also try to find an API to create Office files.

Comment: RomasZ, thanks brother,I think that might be issue, but even those files are not opening that are created in pc. How to open those files without creating? I think you understand my problem

Comment: @NiteshKothari See my edit in the answer, and maybe working sample will help.

Comment: RomasZ, "Installed Location"? will it be work?Thanks

Comment: @NiteshKothari [InstalledLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.package.installedlocation.aspx) gives you access to your project content. But remember that it's read-only, so if you want to modify some files, then you will have to copy them first for example `file.CopyAsync()` and then open the copied file.

Comment: RomasZ, hello brother, I am getting this error: "The system can't find the file specified". Listen, my files are on the platform means on the server.

Comment: @NiteshKothari Have you tried the sample? I'm not sure what kind of server you are talking about - it seems to be other question. If you want to open a remote file, then it should be possible via `Launcher.LaunchUriAsync()` and apropriate Uri.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63150/discussion-between-nitesh-kothari-and-romasz).